# Is there a pseudo-scientific explanation for Vision's ability to pass through walls?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, comics, avengers, avengers-age-of-ultron

In *Age of Ultron*, we learn that

> the Vision has a Vibranium-infused body which the Avengers use to contain the Mind stone. Vision is created by encasing the Mind stone in the Vibranium-infused body with the help of Thor and a Korean scientist.

I know that the Mind Stone is an Infinity Stone with profound power over matter. Thus the mind stone has the power to "deactivate" the boundaries of things like walls, enabling the Vision to walk through walls.  But vibranium is extremely strong and yet the Mind Stone is able to make vibranium pass through walls.

We know *why* vibranium can be made to pass through walls (because we know what the Mind Stone is) but is there an **in-universe mock-science explanation** within the comics and/or movies of *how* the Mind Stone enables him to do this?

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure you're gonna get much of an explanation other than that he can "phase" (like Kitty Pryde).

Comment: He can "alter his density." How does he do this? Kirby-Lee physics.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

According to the Marvel wiki, which cites *Avengers* #332:

> By **interfacing with an unknown dimension** to which he can shunt and from which he can accrue mass, thus becoming either intangible or extraordinarily massive, the Vision can change his density, which at its lowest allows flight and a ghostly, phasing intangibility, and at its heaviest, a density ten times greater than that of depleted uranium, which gives him superhuman strength, immovability, and a diamond-hard near invulnerability.

Notice that, in the comics, Vision's Solar Jewel isn't, as far as I'm aware, identified with

> the Mind Stone or other Infinity Gems.

The Solar Jewel just absorbs sunlight energy and works as a power source.  Lacking further explanation from the movie-verse, I think it's safe to assume that movie Vision uses his jewel in a similar way to power the inter-dimensional "phasing" operation.

Comment: This is also how Wanda is able to get the better of Vision when Hawkeye comes for her in Civil War. She decreases his density so Hawkeye safely passes through his grip, then increases his density until the Earth's gravity pulls him through the floor.